# PHP if statment for boolean/tinyint(1) type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What is the best way for boolen statement to know it is true or false?

In MYSQL database after select boolean it is showing `tinyint(1)` but the issue is when in database the value is 1,

I use `if($var == 1)` result is `false` and `if($var == "1")` is `true`.

But in my localhost (WAMP Server)

`if($var == 1)` is `true`

I am very confused the MYSQL version issue?
By the way I am using laravel framework...

Comment: use === instead of == in your localhost also, you will get the difference. 1 is integer and '1' is string. thats why you face this problem.

Comment: There's absolutely no way that `$var==1` is false while `$var == "1"` is true for the same var. Check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce95da1568c82a6d98f991826802f355e2ea948e

Comment: so why you do not var_dump of $var.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has very little to do with your problem and neither does laravel.

In php, 1 is true, "1" is true, 0 is false, and "0" is false. Therefore, you should be able to write it as `if ($var) {}` unless you abhor such conventions.

Comment: this is a good answer. if you want to use this in proper way jut go to tour model and add this: protected $casts = ['yourColName' => 'boolean'];

Answer (score 0):

Type cast `$var` to `int` when you are assigning `$var` and then do the comparison. Example below:

```
$var = (int) $result['db_field_name'] // $result indicates the database value
if($var == 1) {

}
```

I am sure, this will work on every machine.